# How can you use fgetcsv when there is no enclosure character?

Tags: php, csv, fgetcsv

I'm processing csv files from [geonames.org](http://geonames.org) and as such I need to get csv lines without any enclosures.

Currently [fgetcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) requires that you provide a single character for the `$enclosure` parameter and won't process the CSV data if you don't.

How do you retrieve csv data that has no enclosure character using php native functionality?

Comment: Just read line for line and then parse the data yourself to the desired format

Answer (score 7):

As a possible workaround you can use an odd character as the enclosure:

```
// Read TSV line using 'backspace' as the enclosure character
fgetcsv($stream, 0, "\t", chr(8));
```

Comment: Typo in function name "char", should be "chr".

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, the easiest thing to do is not to use fgetcsv() at all. You can just use the plain [fgets](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php)() function to read each line from the CSV, and then use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)() to create an array of all the different fields per line

Here's a small example:

```
$handle = fopen("foo.csv", "r");

$i = 1;  // for test output

while (($buffer = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
    $fields = explode(";", $buffer);  // assuming that fields are separated with semicolons

    $j = 1;

    // Test output
    echo "Line $i: ";
    // This is just for show, you can use a regular for loop instead
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        echo "Field $j: $field";
        $j++;
    }

    echo "\n";
    $i++;
}

fclose($handle);
```

Comment: This doesn't take into the escaping features provided by fgetcsv and may result in a malformed string where a semicolon is used in the csv data. It's a workable solution for most situations though.